# Inline block ignores padding

Tags: html, css

I want two spans on the same line: an icon and text. I have gotten as far as this.

[image]

First span:

```
span.icon_lock {
    font-size: 50px;
    padding-left: 1em;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}
```

Second span:

```
span.ssltechnology {
    padding-left: 1em;
    display: inline;
}
```

How do I get that second line of the text block to abide by the padding rule?

Comment: Just change display to `display: inline-block`. That should fix it.

Answer (score 3):

don't use `inline` use `inline-blcok`.

```
span.icon_lock {
font-size: 50px;
padding-left: 1em;
float: left;
display: inline-block;
}
```